# How to convert unicode to utf8 in WP

Tags: unicode, utf-8, windows-phone-8

With Windows Phone development, I would like to compose an URI with utf8 encoded with the following code but failed. The result is still unicode but not the form of %D6%DC...

```
        byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        byte[] utf8bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, unicodeBytes);
        char[] utf8Chars = new char[Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(utf8bytes, 0, utf8bytes.Length)];
        Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(utf8bytes, 0, utf8bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0);
        string utf8string = new string(utf8Chars);
        var URI = new Uri("http://www.jpwy.net/gc/search.php?" + utf8string);
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your purpose is, but is there any reason not to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode the string? The default encoding for Urlencode is UTF8.

You should just be able to do replace the above code with

```
var URI = new Uri("http://www.jpwy.net/gc/search.php?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is so convenient, nice. I was using uri.toString so it converted back to Unicode back in the output, I think. I will take this solution.